# ScrollView doesn't start at top

Tags: android, eclipse, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have created a scrollview and inside I placed a LinearLayout containing an image a text and a button. Unfortunately when the app displays this layout the scrollview's starting position is in the middle, displaying the text instead of the top, displaying the image.

I have tried programatically the scrollto and it didnt work. I have also tried the requestfocus in the XML and it didn't work.

Any ideas?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout      
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/rregeneratingcream" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etDescription"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
android:enabled="false"
android:background="#00000000" />        

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonRegeneration"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Next" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is the keyboard open when this happens?

Comment: no and the edittext is disabled

Comment: set edit-ext focus-able false.When click the edit-text to enable the focus of the edit-text.now the scroll view from start position.

Comment: Thanks! This one worked!

Comment: Try with putting ScrollView inside relative layout..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sv"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout      
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etDescription"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
android:focusable="false"
android:background="#00000000" />        

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonRegeneration"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/etDescription"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: didnt work but the key was to set the edittext to focusable false

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Custom Vertical ScrollView like this :

```
package com.xyz.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class VerticalScrollview extends ScrollView {

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview",
                    "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false");
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview",
                    "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false");
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false");
            return false;

        default:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action);
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction());
        return true;
    }
}
```